# I do not know how to use media selectors in my css file correctly to decide which image to load for iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad

there are several html files to guide the user through our app and to introduce him to new features. It is a universal app for iPhone and iPad. If the user selects the help section for the iPhone version, i want to show him images scaled for the iPhone device.

But now there is my problem. In the CSS file there is only one class boximage for all the images. How is it decided which image to load? Should i stuck each image in its own class?

Thanks in advance four your ideas!

Regards,
buk

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
 <style type="text/css">
   @media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .boximage{ background:url(image_name1.jpg)}
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 800px){ 
    .boximage{ background:url(image_name2.jpg)}
    }</style>
```

or Use javascript to find the user-agent and set the image from script.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I have tried your suggestions but nothing happens. I have put my code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2881081) maybe you can have a look. I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: Try this: 

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .boximage{ background:url(error.JPG) no-repeat;}
    }
@media all and (min-width: 800px){ 
    .boximage{ background:url(error.JPG) no-repeat;}
    }
.boximage{
 height:300px;
 }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="boximage">
 hai
 </div>
</body>
</html>`